# Laravel 8 error route | The GET method is not supported for this route

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-jetstream

Laravel V 8 Jetstream.
This problem appeared with me after I uploaded and published the project on shared hosting
Error message

> Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
> The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods:
> HEAD.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fv8YX.png)

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

route code

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/dashboard',function () {
        return view('dashboard');
    })->name('dashboard');;

    Route::get('/upload', function () {
        return view('uploadpdf');
    })->name('upload'); 

});
```

Comment: You omitted one of the key parts of this question... What route are you trying to navigate to when you get this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you encounter this problem, always check the settings in your .env and config files
The error was found in config.php - /bootstrap/cache/config.php.
I did not configure the location settings like APP_URL and the paths of some directories were pointing to my computer
Good luck everyone
Greetings from the Dzsecurity company team for helping to find a solution